# loading photo from database into angular material form

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new with angular material and what I want to do is to display the photo that I receive from database into a form. I can retrieve the photo address that already uploaded into my asset folder and if I use this value with **matInput** it has the photo address but I don't know how I can use this value with an image tag.

this is my componnent.ts file

```
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.newForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [''],
      email: [''],
      phone: [''],
      userPhoto:['']
    })
    this.newForm.controls['email'].disable();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.receiveUserProfile().subscribe(result => {
      this.newForm.patchValue({
          name: result.name,
          email: result.email,
          phone: result.phone,
          userPhoto: result.userPhoto,
        }); 
    })
  }
```

and this is part of my component.html file

```
<mat-form-field class="register-full-width">
    <mat-label>Phone</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="phone">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="register-full-width">
    <input #photo matInput formControlName="userPhoto">
</mat-form-field>

<img src="" height="200" width="350">
```

all other three fields display correctly as the value in input tags and also photo. but what I want is instead of using **formControlName="userPhoto"**  use this value in **img src** to display the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply get the value of the `formControl` and bind it to the `src-attribute` of the `img-tag` like:

```
<img [src]="newForm.get('userPhoto').value"  height="200" width="350">
```

Note the brackets around `[src]` for one-way binding the `src-attribute` to the property value. You can read more about it [here.](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property)